# For Ruby on Rails, how do you use delayed_job (and add generator)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator

This is for http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

the example says:

```
script/generate delayed_job_migration
```

if I run it

```
$ script/generate delayed_job_migration
Couldn't find 'delayed_job_migration' generator
```

On github, there is a `generators` folder, an `init.rb`, a `lib` folder, and a `tasks` folder, where should they go into our project?  (using Rails 3.0)

It also says add code like this:

```
class NewsletterJob < Struct.new(:text, :emails)
  def perform
    emails.each { |e| NewsletterMailer.deliver_text_to_email(text, e) }
  end    
end  

Delayed::Job.enqueue NewsletterJob.new('lorem ipsum...', Customers.find(:all).collect(&:email))
```

but where should this code go?  to the controller or in a lib file?  and how do you invoke it?  I suppose the `enqueue` code need to only run once really?

Answer (score 1):

Try the collective idea delayed_job http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job . I think it is more complete, I have used it and I had no problem.

1) Just install

2) run the migration

3) start the workers with the command

```
rake jobs:work
```

4) put inside the controller the command with the delay. For example **@video.delay.convert**

And you are ready.

Sometimes you might need to restart the workers to take effect the new changes you made.